# Python argparse: name parameters

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a program that use argparse, for parsing some arguments that I need.

for now I have this:

`parser.add_argument('--rename', type=str, nargs=2, help='some help')`

when I run this script I see this:

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --rename RENAME RENAME
                        some help
```

How can I change my code in that way that the help "page" will show me:

```
--rename OLDFILE NEWFILE
```

Can I then use **OLDFILE** and **NEWFILE** value in this way?

```
args.rename.oldfile
args.rename.newfile
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you set `metavar=('OLDFILE', 'NEWFILE')`:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--rename', type=str, nargs=2, help='some help',
                    metavar=('OLDFILE', 'NEWFILE'))
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Then `test.py -h` yields

```
usage: test.py [-h] [--rename OLDFILE NEWFILE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --rename OLDFILE NEWFILE
                        some help
```

You can then access the arguments with

```
oldfile, newfile = args.rename
```

If you really want to access the oldfile with `args.rename.oldfile`
you could set up a custom action:

```
import argparse
class RenameAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest,
                argparse.Namespace(
                    **dict(zip(('oldfile', 'newfile'),
                               values))))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--rename', type=str, nargs=2, help='some help',
                    metavar=('OLDFILE', 'NEWFILE'),
                    action=RenameAction)
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.rename.oldfile)
```

but it extra code does not really seem worth it to me.

Comment: thanks for all details provided... "oldfile, newfile = args.rename" will do the job :)

Answer (score 1):

Read the argparse documentation (http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#metavar):

> Different values of nargs may cause the metavar to be used multiple times. Providing a tuple to metavar specifies a different display for each of the arguments:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
>>> parser.add_argument('-x', nargs=2)
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs=2, metavar=('bar', 'baz'))
>>> parser.print_help()
usage: PROG [-h] [-x X X] [--foo bar baz]

optional arguments:
 -h, --help     show this help message and exit
 -x X X
 --foo bar baz
```